# Inkscape: what are "line" objects?

Tags: import, svg, inkscape

What is a "line" object in [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape)? Drawing lines in
Inkscape is by using the tool "Draw Bezier curves and
straight lines (Shift+F6)". This creates objects of another
type, "path".

Using Inkscape: is there a way to convert an object of type
"line" into an object of the more general type "path"?

I have imported a drawing (mostly lines, rectangles and
text) that has been through [Adobe Illustrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator): originally
made in Inkscape, imported into Illustrator, edited, saved
from Illustrator as [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), imported into Inkscape.

Sample from the imported SVG file:

```
<path
   id="path5855"
   stroke="#000000"
   d="  M320.198,275.935" />

<line
   fill="none"
   stroke="#000000"
   x1="348.553"
   y1="45.097"
   x2="348.553"
   y2="185.346"
   id="line3368" />
```

**Update 1**: I have inspected the original XML (SVG) file
from 2006 and it does not contain any "line" XML tags. Thus
it must be a crime of Adobe Illustrator.

When a line is selected in this imported SVG file the bottom
panel displays: "Line in root. Click selection to toggle
scale/rotation handles.".

When a line is selected that was drawn in Inkscape the
bottom panel displays: "Path (2 nodes) in Layer 1.  Click
selection to toggle scale/rotation handles."

What is the difference between "line" and "path"?

Is "line" some kind of read-only/non-editable object?

---

A generic term like "line" is not easy to use in search, but I have now found
the definitions for "line" and "path":

```
SVG line: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_line.asp

SVG path: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp
```

Platform: Inkscape v0.46 (2008-03-10), Windows XP 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Did you search for "L" or "l"?

Comment: Also, what is your goal? To be able to edit that object since Inkscape is treating it differently? Can you post the SVG source, etc.?

Comment: The goal is to use the tool "Edit path by nodes (F2)" on objects of type "Line". E.g. by first converting them to the more general type "Path". And I would like know why Inkscape can handle objects of type "Line", but is nowhere to found in the Inkscape documentation (as far I as can tell).

Comment: @Jared Updike: How do you make a web search case sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

A line is just what it says, a straight line.
A path is more versatile and can represent almost any curve.

You can always convert a line into a path, but not vice versa in the general case.
In Inkscape use the menu item `Path/Object to Path` or the keyboard shortcut `Shift+Ctrl+C`.

You can't edit nodes on line objects because a line object has just start and endpoint, but no nodes.

As a path can also be a straight line Inkscape doesn't bother to create line elements.
It always creates path elements. If your SVG file contains line elements Inkscape can read them and you can manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is built around SVG:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/

(although Inkscape supports more effects and probably more features than most browsers, IIRC, YMMV)

Wikipedia's [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Functionality) entry says that although a Path is very general (and I remember from experience can represent line(s) as well as splines), there are Line objects as a basic shapes.

Perhaps you can load the .svg file in a text editor (if you are so inclined) and inspect the SVG xml code to determine how it is representing the data.